# The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-getx, state-management, textformfield

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════ setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. occured when i auto add value in textfield controller and also i have used valuelistnable builder at the top anyone can suggest ?

i am selecting textformfield value from another page and assign value to textfield

Comment: Kindly, add tried code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need wrap your code where you assign value to `Textfield` into `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` block.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  /// update your widget here
});
```